# Why does the plot() method of the Axes object created by twinx() change the Formatter of xaxis object?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, formatter

I found a strange behavior of the `plot()` method of the Axes object created with `twinx()` method, when plotting a Pandas Series with Datetime Index.

**First case:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Create a Formatter object
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

# plot
data = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=pd.to_datetime(['20180101', '20180201', '20180301']))
ax1.plot(data)

# Set the major formatter of x axis
x = ax1.xaxis
x.set_major_formatter(fmt)

plt.show()
```

The above codes create an Axes object, plot a Pandas Series indexed with Datetime, and then set the major formatter of the x axis. We can check that the formatter of x is `fmt` by `x.get_major_formatter()`.

**Second case:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Create a Formatter object
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Set the major formatter of x axis
x = ax1.xaxis
x.set_major_formatter(fmt)

# plot
data = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=pd.to_datetime(['20180101', '20180201', '20180301']))
ax1.plot(data)

plt.show()
```

In this case, I set the major formatter first, and then plot the Pandas Series. Using `x.get_major_formatter()`, we can check that the formatter of x axis is still `fmt`. The plot() method **doesn't change** the major formatter of x axis.

The strange thing happens when I create another Axes using `twinx()`.

**Third case:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Create a Formatter object
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

# plot
data = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=pd.to_datetime(['20180101', '20180201', '20180301']))
ax1.plot(data)

# Set the major formatter of x axis
x = ax1.xaxis
x.set_major_formatter(fmt)

# Create another Axes
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(data)

plt.show()
```

In this case, I create another Axes object sharing the x axis with `ax1`, then plot the Pandas Series. If we check the major formatter of `x` using `x.get_major_formatter()`, we could get a `PandasAutoDateFormatter` object, rather than `fmt`. The `plot()` method of `ax2` has changed the major formatter of x axis.

Is this a bug?

Comment: when you use `twinx`, the two axes share an `x` axis, so of course, if you change the formatter of one, it must also change the formatter of the other

Comment: @tom Of course. But in the second case, the plot() method of Axes object didn't change the Formatter of the x axis. However, in the third case, the plot() method of  the new Axes object changed it. This is what I am confused about.